# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: InvalidClientTokenId

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs, boto3

I went through the quickstart located here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html

I installed the AWS CLI and configured it with my valid keys. I've double checked in the ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config

At this point I should be able to run my py script with `python bin/process_sqs_messages.py` at the command prompt. The script looks like this:

```
__author__ = 'chris'
import boto3

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

# List SQS queues
response = sqs.list_queues()

print(response['QueueUrls'])
```

I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) 
when calling the ListQueues operation: No account found for the given parameters
```

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/process_sqs_messages.py", line 12, in <module>
response = client.list_queues()
File "/Users/xxxx/.environments/xxxx_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/Users/xxxxx/.environments/xxxxx_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the ListQueues operation: No account found for the given parameters
```

My guess is that i'm missing a session token, but i'm not sure and if I am where/how do I get one? The sample doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: If your credentials are in ~/.aws/credentials then you don't need to supply them to the client constructor.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The code i added here is my second attempt to coding the script and making it work. Let me edit it to reflect my initial script.

Comment: If you generated temporary credentials then you'll have an access key, a secret key, and a session token. Otherwise you'll have the first two only. Example of the former: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html.

Comment: They aren't temporary credentials...they are my permanent credentials

Comment: I would use the awscli and attempt to validate the same set of credentials, by running aws ec2 describe-regions and aws sqs list-queues. If you see the same symptoms, which I presume you will, and you're convinced that the credentials are valid, then I'd raise an AWS support case.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new user and magically they work again. Must have had my credentials invalidated somewhere, but that user still existed and that user's credentials matched inside awscli.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created new users/keys but it didn't work. Also, I double-checked the following.

- My AWS keys were correct.
- Policy/Permission was right.
- The machine time was correct as well.

It was my old terminal that was causing the problem(which I didn't shut nearly for weeks) so After closing it, I just relaunched it and it worked perfectly fine.